# I am not able to load Self Reference in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently having an issue with a self reference relationship.

I have the table `Customer` which can have a parent (also a `Customer`) like this:

```
class CustomerModel(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'customer'

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'))
     parent = relationship("CustomerModel", foreign_keys=[parent_id])
```

So my problem is that when I'm trying to load the parent, the following query is built by SQLAlchemy:

Lets take this customer for example: `Customer(id=1, parent_id=10)`

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE 1 = customer.parent_id
```

So the WHERE condition is wrong because it compares the `parent_id` to the `id` of the customer I'm trying to load the parent from.

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE 10 = customer.parent_id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found the answer.

I need to add the param remote_side like this:

```
 class CustomerModel(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'customer'

      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'))
      parent = relationship("CustomerModel", foreign_keys=[parent_id], remote_side=[id])
```